# Difference between interactive Python console and Django's "manage.py shell"

Tags: python, django, console

I know of two ways to enter commands into the Python interpreter:

1. Directly type `python` in terminal
2. If you have installed `django`, run `python manage.py shell`

I want to know the difference between those two methods. In the first option, we can import and execute what we want.
Some is in 2nd option, what is difference between these two..

Comment: Read the [first line of the docs for the shell command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/django-admin/#shell)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Directly typing python, just starts the interpreter.

Using manage.py within a django project sets the environment so that you can interact with your project objects in the shell. As noted [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial02/#playing-with-the-api):

> We’re using this instead of simply typing “python”, because manage.py
>   sets the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable, which gives
>   Django the Python import path to your mysite/settings.py file.